Enabling Scrolling And Zooming in View
I have a SwiftUI view with a grid of squares. I'm able to zoom in and out of the squares by holding the command key down and using my mouse scroll view. I can't currently, however, scroll vertically within the view at all. How do I get both enabled?
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var scale: CGFloat = 1.0
    @State private var contentSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 600, height: 400)
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView([.vertical, .horizontal]) {
            CustomZoomableView(scale: $scale, contentSize: $contentSize)
                .frame(width: contentSize.width, height: contentSize.height)
                .clipped()
        }
        .frame(width: 600, height: 400)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

struct CustomZoomableView: NSViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var scale: CGFloat
    @Binding var contentSize: CGSize

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSCustomZoomView {
        let view = NSCustomZoomView()
        view.scale = scale
        return view
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSCustomZoomView, context: Context) {
        nsView.scale = scale
        nsView.updateFrameSize()
    }
}

class NSCustomZoomView: NSView {
    var scale: CGFloat = 1.0 {
        didSet {
            updateFrameSize()
            self.needsDisplay = true
        }
    }

    func updateFrameSize() {
        if let clipView = self.superview as? NSClipView {
            let newWidth = 600 * scale
            let newHeight = 400 * scale
            clipView.documentView?.setFrameSize(CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
        }
    }

    override var isFlipped: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func scrollWheel(with event: NSEvent) {
        guard event.modifierFlags.contains(.command) else { return }
        let delta = event.deltaY
        let zoomFactor = delta > 0 ? 1.1 : 0.9
        self.scale = max(0.1, min(self.scale * zoomFactor, 10.0))
    }

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
        guard let context = NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext else { return }

        context.clear(dirtyRect)
        context.setFillColor(NSColor.blue.cgColor)

        let numSquares: Int = 10
        let spacing: CGFloat = 2.0
        let squareSize: CGFloat = (dirtyRect.width / CGFloat(numSquares) - spacing) * scale
        let gridFullSize: CGFloat = (squareSize + spacing) * CGFloat(numSquares)
        let startX: CGFloat = (dirtyRect.width - gridFullSize) / 2
        let startY: CGFloat = (dirtyRect.height - gridFullSize) / 2

        for row in 0..<numSquares {
            for col in 0..<numSquares {
                let xPosition = startX + CGFloat(col) * (squareSize + spacing)
                let yPosition = startY + CGFloat(row) * (squareSize + spacing)
                context.fill(CGRect(x: xPosition, y: yPosition, width: squareSize, height: squareSize))
            }
        }
    }
}


